# Does SEC/DIV know on oscilloscope always adjust capture sample rate (or acquisition speed)?

Tags: oscilloscope

I have an oscilloscope called Tektronix TDS 224. I find it confusing how the horizontal SEC/DIV knob actually changes the resolution of acquisition. Is this how most scopes are?

Comment: Depends on the scope, and how "deep" its acquisition memory is. Shallow memory means that sample rate needs to be more closely correlated with horizontal scale.

Answer (score 0):

The TDS2xx DSO is limited to 2500 points on the display so you may use delayed triggers to capture spikes with better resolution between long intervals. This was called the window function on horizontal sweep.